# How do I make a multi-coloured scrollbar?

Tags: css

I want to have a scrollbar that has multiple colours, including the background.
I'm going for a Windows-XP style approach. Here's my current code I use to make the scrollbar 'blue'.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #6699cc;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #8abbeb;
}
```

I think adding a border will do it, but I don't know how to add it.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think adding a border will do it, but I don't know how to add it.

if you want to add a border to it, you can use `outline`. you can add it to the `track`, `thumb` or wherever you want the border to be

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #6699cc;
  outline: 5px solid red;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #8abbeb;
}
```

but sometimes it only shows the outline at the top and bottom idk why

an alternative will be using `border`

```css
border: 5px solid red;
```

Comment: This only makes the outline show on the top and bottom, is there a way to get it on the sides?

Comment: @rat1819 turns out you can you `border` instead of `outline`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've totally understood, but you already are putting background colors on the thumb and the actual bar so you can change to linear-gradient background images to get this sort of thing:
[image]

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #6699cc;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue, orange, cyan);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #8abbeb;
}
```

```html
<body>A long body</body>
```

Comment: I'm not seeking for a gradient, yet this helps me a lot to get the feel.

Comment: Could you describe bit more what you want it to look like as I hadn't quite understood.  Are you looking for a more rounded, 3d sort of efftect? If you have a mockup image you could post that perhaps?Most things seems achievable with gradients!

Comment: I'm looking for something like this: https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/19338979/Scrolling_04.0.gif (Windows XP/Vista)